# Get rid of Debian on a dual disk dual boot?

Tags: debian, windows-8.1, multi-boot

I've got dual disks, Windows 8.1 64-bit installed on my 500GB HDD, and Debian Jessie installed on my 1TB HDD. Can someone walk me through how to wipe that disk and get rid of GRUB, too? I know how to do this exact thing with one disk, but I'm pretty sure it's different with 2 disks.

Comment: Hi, see if this link will help you after you format your Linux partition from Windows 8.1  - [http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/184344-how-do-i-restore-master-boot-record.html]. The question is on Ubuntu but urs is Debian. That' the only difference.  If you do not have Hiren boot CD, you can download it from [http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download]. If you do not want to write a CD, there is the USB booting option available too

Comment: @Prasanna What do I do before I restore the master boot record? I've already got a way to do that.

Comment: @Prasanna Could I instead just use a recovery USB for Windows? I've got plenty of USBs to do it with.

Comment: Does that let you go into DOS prompt? Meaning to say - will that allow you to run the command `bootrec<space>/fixmbr` command. If its a yes then go ahead

Comment: @Prasanna It does. Thank you so much, and I'll comment back if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step-1: Get Hiren CD or recovery USB for Windows or equivalent
Step-2: From Windows Disk management window - locate your Linux partition and select format
Step-3 Reboot your PC with Hiren CD (select boot from CD)
Step-4: Locate some software that will allow you to be in MS DOS prompt within the Hiren CD - Select it.   Step-5: Once the program opens type `bootrec<space>/fixmbr`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply/whatever this is. I did everything like you said (except replacing hiren's with recovery usb) and it worked PERFECTLY! Thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome. You can upvote the answer as well in addition to accepting it as an answer  :-)